# How to grab files generated by a subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want to run some command line scripts from within my python program. These scripts generates some output files. I want to grab these output files from the subprocess call as object in my python program, while canceling generation of files on disk. Problem is I don't know how to do it, or whether that is even possible.

A simple example would look like this:

```
#foo.py
fout1 = open("temp1.txt","w")
fout2 = open("temp2.txt","w")

fout1.write("fout1")
fout2.write("fout2")

fout1.close()
fout2.close()

#test.py
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python","foo.py"], ????????) #what arguments to use to grab temp1.txt and temp2.txt
print(process.??????)  #how to access those files
```

I am familiar with subprocess.Popen so that is what the example code uses, but I am open to the use of other modules too if they could do it.

Comment: you want to redirect output of your subprocess? if subprocess creates files there's nothing you can do to prevent that from happening.

Comment: yes that is what I want to do.